# Unable to access local sound from a particular URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router, html5-audio

I’m experiencing an issue accessing a local sound in my React app that uses React Router. The sounds are all located in the public/sounds/SFX folder.

I’m playing it like this:

```
let audio = new Audio(audio_object.path);
audio.play();
```

where the path is something like:
“sounds/SFX/sfx_error.mp3”
or
“sounds/SFX/sfx_sparkle.mp3”

All other sounds in the app play correctly, however if I’m on the url:
http://localhost:3000/childSelector/menu
it fails with the message:

http://localhost:3000/childSelector/sounds/SFX/sfx_modal_window_opening.mp3 404 (Not Found). Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

It’s not a problem with the particular sound b/c I can play it from other urls. The problem is that it’s trying to look in a childSelector folder that isn’t there. But I don’t know why for this url only it’s appending that bit.

If I’m one level up on the route (http://localhost:3000/childSelector/) and I play a sound from there, then it works fine. It seems that it’s able to strip off one level of the path, but if I go further than one level down it fails. This is my assumption, as it’s the only difference between this url and others in the app. I got to this route by pushing directly into history, if that matters:

```
this.props.history.push('/childSelector/menu');
```

but I’ve done that elsewhere in the app and it didn't affected audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution and I think I was overthinking it.

```
let audio = new Audio(document.location.origin +"/"+ audio_object.path);
```

Now, plenty sounds that weren't triggered from the base url were playing fine before this fix and I can't say why--it was only broken for urls that were two levels deep, but with this solution all urls play as expected.