# DOMException: "Failed to load because no supported source was found (404)"

Tags: javascript, html, audio, src

```
const playMusic = (track) => {
         currentSong.src = "/songs/" + track + ".mp3";
         currentSong.play().catch(error => {
             console.error('Error playing music:', error);
    });
};
```

So I was trying to play the audio that is accessing from this link(http://127.0.0.1:3000/songs/) but keeps showing me a404 error:

> DOM Exception: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

Also I try to play others songs but it keeps showing me the same error. When i try to acess it directly by the url, same problem occurred. I am a beginner so it is getting difficult for me to correct this error..

Comment: Do the solutions in this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674223/domexception-failed-to-load-because-no-supported-source-was-found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to access local sound from a particular URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955277/unable-to-access-local-sound-from-a-particular-url)